# Can I make rsync output only the summary?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I use rsync to backup a directory which is very big, containing many sub-directories and files, so I don't want to see the "incremental file list". I just want to know the summary in the end. If I use the argument `-q`, nothing is output at all. Can I make rsync output only the summary?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the following:

```
rsync -vr src/ dest/ | sed '0,/^$/d'
```

Explanation: `rsync` is run in verbose mode using the `-v` flag. It outputs a detailed file list, an empty line and the summary. Now `sed` is used to take advantage of the fact that the summary is separated by an empty line. Everything up to the first empty line is not printed to stdout. `^$` matches an empty line and `d` prevents it from being output.

Comment: interesting hack, but look at the other answers for real solution.

Answer (score 103):

Thanks to a [tip by Wayne Davison](http://samba.2283325.n4.nabble.com/summary-only-in-output-td2506833.html), I use the `--stats` option for backup:

```
rsync -a --stats src/ dest/
```

Nice little summary at the end, e.g.

```
Number of files: 6765
Number of files transferred: 0
Total file size: 709674 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
(10 more lines)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted response.

Comment: Currently, this answer uses `-m`, but I don't see a need for it. The following should be minimally enough: `rsync -a --stats src/ dest/`

Comment: ... also, a precondition to avoid the "file list" is NOT using the flags `-v` and `-P`.

Comment: Although that's a good answer, it's not solving "...don't want to see the incremental file list..." part of the question.

Comment: When we add previous answer's `sed` section to this solution, it's an accepted response. :) Thanks! :+1

Comment: @csonuryilmaz I didn't include it because I confess I don't understand sed very well, and it didn't work for me in cygwin/Win11 -- it only omitted the first line, which was "receiving incremental file list". Maybe it's an LF versus CRLF thing.

Comment: @BobStein you're right. Sed implementation is a little bit different on other platforms. I couldn't use the same `sed` command between mac os and gnu/linux on a case. We should test `sed` part on various platforms.

Comment: indeed `-m` means prune empty directories and makes zero sense to get included in this answer.

Comment: Thanks @cregox and @Abdull, I removed the `-m`. Still needs work on `sed` filters that work on multiple platforms.

Comment: still need work on sed filters?!

Comment: @cregox, when I say "still needs work on sed filters" I mean that my answer might be improved by piping through a sed filter as [the other answer does](https://serverfault.com/a/526729/161152), but using a syntax that works well on Linux, Mac, Windows, etc.

Comment: nah, i wouldn't bother with it. the summary stands good by itself! 

Answer (score 12):

Try this command

```
rsync -a --info=progress2 --stats source destination
```

Output

```
32,342,135  10%  134.45kB/s    0:03:54 (xfr#386, to-chk=1059/7326)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way, it displays very little data, only the total count:

```
rsync -axHSEAXhh --partial **--info=stats** --modify-window=1 --delete --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/boot/initramfs*","/boot/grub/grub.cfg","/etc/fstab","/etc/default/grub"} / ${PATH_ROOT}/
```

Very useful variant for scripts! rsync  version 3.2.4

Comment: Please format the command as "code", this would improve the readability. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can run dry run, count files, and run it with pv command:

```bash
dry_run_output=$(rsync -avn --stats source/ destination/)
file_count=$(echo "$dry_run_output" | awk '/to-chk/ || /Number of created files/ {gsub(",", "", $5); print $5}')
rsync -avz --stats source/ destination/ | awk '/to-chk/ || /Number of created files/ {print}' | pv -l -s "$file_count"
```